# geom_bar() with sorted values

Tags: r, plot, geom-bar

I have following data.

```
df <- data.frame(name1 = c("Chi", "Ron", "Gen", "Ral", "Cha", "Det", "Har", "Was"),
                 value1 = c(641, 548, 459, 367, 366, 324, 317, 309))
```

I want to create a bar plot to visualize this data.
The bars should be in increasing or decreasing order of values each with different color.
The legend should show which color belongs to which name.
How do I do it using `geom_bar()` function.

Answer (score 0):

convert `name1` to factor and set levels by ordering `name1` based on `value1`

```
df$name1 = factor(df$name1, df$name1[order(df$value1)])
ggplot(df[order(df$value1),], aes(x = name1, y=value1, fill = name1)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question! But you should got through this [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) how to technically ask a question on stackoverflow:

We could use

1. `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`
2. `reorder` `+` for ascending `-` for descending:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(name1, +value1), value1))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]